# how to add alert if after condition in actionDelete yii

Tags: yii

Here's my code so far:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
    $jenis = Usaha::model()->findByAttributes(array('id_jenis' => $id));
    if($jenis==''){
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
    }
    else {
        throw new CHttpException(400, "data tidak bisa di hapus karena berhubungan dengan data yang lain");
    }

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), 
    // we should not redirect the browser
    if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
}
```

Can i get some alert another exception 404, or can i customize my alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the exception yes.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpException

And here for the codes:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpException#statusCode-detail